# How can I validate a form field value against a variable with jQuery Validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm sure there must be a simple solution to this..

I simply want to create a rudimentary human verification tool for an online form. In pseudo-code, something like

```
$answer = "foo";

if (form['question'] == $foo){
    // Proceed
} else {
    // Fail
}
```

The jQuery docs seem to have an equalTo method but this is to compare a form field with another form value..

Any tips greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a look at JQuery Validation plugin at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation. Consider the following example:
[image]

You may change the rules as explained in the plugin to implement your custom validations.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this plugin? You can use it to make fields required, validate for certain value types (number, string, credit card, etc), and I believe you can write callback functions to validate for specific values.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Answer (score 1):

```
var answer = 'foo';
if ($('#question').val() == answer) {
  // Proceed
} else {
  // Fail.
}
```